# How to express this idea in a better way?

Tags: word-choice, phrase, equivalent-phrase

I'd like to say something like "...but my heart belongs to Hong Kong" as a possible response to "where do you live?" So the full context might be "I live in X but my heart belongs to Hong Kong". Meaning I'd always prefer to be in Hong Kong. Is there a way to say this that does not sound weird in Chinese?

Google Translate gives me:

> 但我的心脏属于香港 (*Is this a good way to phrase the idea ?*)

I am hoping someone can provide a better way to say this (especially if the direct translation sounds awkward).

Please feel free to follow-up if any clarification required.

Comment: 心脏 means `heart` as in the **organ** not as a metaphorical object! 心属于XXX is o.k. but probably not the most natural way to express this...

Comment: @user3306356 In this case can 心属于 reference a place as in the sense of longing to be (at).. someplace?

Comment: you know there's a phrase 乐不思蜀, I think you could use a play on words and say that you 思 another place instead and that would sound more natural...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may quote from 关羽（kuanyu） 身在曹营心在汉

So you can use 身在xx心在港.

Another common 1 is 我虽然身在xx但我的心永远属于(or 向着facing) 香港

Answer (score 2):

One possibility would perhaps be:

住在X城但是香港一直在我的心中

Comment: Interesting. It's very precise. I am not sure if it carries the same carefree tone that the original sentiment in English conveys. If one were to say this idea casually, would it be expressed differently?

Answer (score 2):

我身處XX, 但仍然心繫香江.

1) "香江" is a well-known elegant way of saying "香港"

2) "仍然" is optional.